# Android 4.0.x (ICS) WebView does not update UI clicking <a> tags

Tags: android, webview, reload

I need WebView to show a HTML page A, there are  hyperlink tags in page A, which will open page B when clicked. On action bar of my Activity, I have a Button which will call WebView.reload() when clicked. This should be a very simple case of WebView.

PROBLEM:
When running my app on Andorid 4.0.3 or 4.0.4, after click hyperlink ( tags) in page A, Android WevView stays on page A, nothing happend.

What-I-tried:
1. when the problem occurrs, click reload button, WevView is displaying page B correctly.
2. modify source code of page A and B, remove CSS code which affect how  tag displays. Then WebView can jump to page B correctly after click hyperlinks in page A.

I think this is a bug in Android 4.0.x, It is not possilbe to remove CSS in HTML, I am stuck with the "reload solution".

Does anyone know the root cause of this bug or a better soluton?
Thanks

Comment: Thsi bug could not reproduce on other Android platform, only 4.0.x have this bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by WORKAROUND in web page source, not Android WebView. 
add the following javascript inside html body:

```
try{
    document.documentElement.clientHeight
} catch (e) {
};
```

above js trys to read web window height, but it will force a refresh of web page.
That's how this js solved this issue.

I guess this should be a bug in Android 4.0.3/4.0.4. But currently you can use this workaround to avoid it, only if your WebView load web pages developed by you.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebChromeClient for webView fucntionality it should work.Even then you are unable to load the html than debug your code and use alternative which function is not working . because java script and CSS both works in web view only the case if you have made mistake in java script or css thnt it should do strange behavior(not loading/blank load/hang screen).

Comment: I did set a WebChromeClient into WebView, but did not fix this problem.

Comment: I inject window.onerror in js but it did not get called when the problem occurrs. Furthermore, I do not think there is error in js or css because the problem does not exsit after WebView.reload()

Comment: you should check one more thing : 1) before load webview first it set null AND THEN LOAD WEBVIEW 2)after load web view jst call reload. i mean call load and jst next step call reload again .